# Is there a way to turn the value in multiple columns to the column name?

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a dataframe:

```
  df <- structure(list(ziekten = c(1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 2, 2, 2), voedselallergie = c("no", 
"no", "no", "no", "no", "no", "no", "no", "no", "no"), ziekaller2 = c("no", 
"no", "no", "no", "no", "no", "no", "no", "no", "no"), hooikoorts = c("yes", 
"no", "no", "no", "no", "no", "yes", "no", "no", "no"), ziekaller4 = c("no", 
"no", "no", "no", "no", "no", "no", "no", "no", "no"), ziekaller5 = c("no", 
"no", "no", "no", "no", "no", "no", "no", "no", "no"), anderallergie = c("no", 
"no", "no", "no", "no", "no", "no", "no", "no", "no"), astma = c("no", 
"no", "no", "no", "no", "no", "no", "no", "no", "no"), ziekdiabet1 = c("no", 
"no", "no", "no", "no", "no", "no", "no", "no", "no")), row.names = c(NA, 
-10L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

This is just a minor set of the total amount of columns I have in the actual dataframe but I would like to change the values within a column to the corresponding column name. I know how to do it with `ifelse` or `case_when` but this isn't efficient.

The first column can stay as is, so from the second column onwards, I would like to change the value 'yes' to the column name. This would be the result:

```
df_new <-  structure(list(ziekten = c(1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 2, 2, 2), voedselallergie = c(NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), ziekaller2 = c(NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), hooikoorts = c("hooikoorts", NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, "hooikoorts", NA, NA, NA), ziekaller4 = c(NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), ziekaller5 = c(NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), anderallergie = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), astma = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA), ziekdiabet1 = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA)), row.names = c(NA, -10L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", 
    "data.frame"))
```

Hope you can help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We could use `cur_column()` in `across`

```
library(dplyr) #version >= 1.1.0
df %>%
   mutate(across(-1,  ~case_match(.x, "yes" ~ cur_column(),
                .default = NA_character_)))
```

-output

```
# A tibble: 10 × 9
   ziekten voedselallergie ziekaller2 hooikoorts ziekaller4 ziekaller5 anderallergie astma ziekdiabet1
     <dbl> <chr>           <chr>      <chr>      <chr>      <chr>      <chr>         <chr> <chr>      
 1       1 <NA>            <NA>       hooikoorts <NA>       <NA>       <NA>          <NA>  <NA>       
 2       2 <NA>            <NA>       <NA>       <NA>       <NA>       <NA>          <NA>  <NA>       
 3       2 <NA>            <NA>       <NA>       <NA>       <NA>       <NA>          <NA>  <NA>       
 4       2 <NA>            <NA>       <NA>       <NA>       <NA>       <NA>          <NA>  <NA>       
 5       2 <NA>            <NA>       <NA>       <NA>       <NA>       <NA>          <NA>  <NA>       
 6       2 <NA>            <NA>       <NA>       <NA>       <NA>       <NA>          <NA>  <NA>       
 7       1 <NA>            <NA>       hooikoorts <NA>       <NA>       <NA>          <NA>  <NA>       
 8       2 <NA>            <NA>       <NA>       <NA>       <NA>       <NA>          <NA>  <NA>       
 9       2 <NA>            <NA>       <NA>       <NA>       <NA>       <NA>          <NA>  <NA>       
10       2 <NA>            <NA>       <NA>       <NA>       <NA>       <NA>          <NA>  <NA>
```

---

Or in `base R` - one-liner (the first line is just to convert to data.frame) without using the ifelse or case_when (as mentioned in the OP's post)

```
out <- as.data.frame(df)
out[-1] <- names(df)[-1][NA^(df[-1] != "yes") * col(df[-1])]
```

Answer (score 2):

One liner base R:

```r
df[-1] <- Map(function(nm, x) ifelse(x == "yes", nm, nm[NA]),
              names(df)[-1], df[-1])
df
# # A tibble: 10 × 9
#    ziekten voedselallergie ziekaller2 hooikoorts ziekaller4 ziekaller5 anderallergie astma ziekdiabet1
#      <dbl> <chr>           <chr>      <chr>      <chr>      <chr>      <chr>         <chr> <chr>      
#  1       1 <NA>            <NA>       hooikoorts <NA>       <NA>       <NA>          <NA>  <NA>       
#  2       2 <NA>            <NA>       <NA>       <NA>       <NA>       <NA>          <NA>  <NA>       
#  3       2 <NA>            <NA>       <NA>       <NA>       <NA>       <NA>          <NA>  <NA>       
#  4       2 <NA>            <NA>       <NA>       <NA>       <NA>       <NA>          <NA>  <NA>       
#  5       2 <NA>            <NA>       <NA>       <NA>       <NA>       <NA>          <NA>  <NA>       
#  6       2 <NA>            <NA>       <NA>       <NA>       <NA>       <NA>          <NA>  <NA>       
#  7       1 <NA>            <NA>       hooikoorts <NA>       <NA>       <NA>          <NA>  <NA>       
#  8       2 <NA>            <NA>       <NA>       <NA>       <NA>       <NA>          <NA>  <NA>       
#  9       2 <NA>            <NA>       <NA>       <NA>       <NA>       <NA>          <NA>  <NA>       
# 10       2 <NA>            <NA>       <NA>       <NA>       <NA>       <NA>          <NA>  <NA>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `names` in `lapply`.

```
df[-1] <- lapply(names(df)[-1], \(x) c(NA, x)[1L + (df[[x]] == "yes")])
```

Or use an index (e.g. in case of duplicated names).

```
df[-1] <- lapply(2:ncol(df), \(i) c(NA, names(df)[[i]])[1L + (df[[i]] == "yes")])
```

Benchmark

```
library(dplyr)
out <- as.data.frame(df)
bench::mark(check=FALSE,
akrun1 = {x <- df %>%
   mutate(across(-1,  ~case_match(.x, "yes" ~ cur_column(),
                                  .default = NA_character_)))},
akrun2 = {out[-1] <- names(df)[-1][NA^(df[-1] != "yes") * col(df[-1])]},
r2evans = {out[-1] <- Map(function(nm, x) ifelse(x == "yes", nm, nm[NA]),
              names(df)[-1], df[-1])},
GKi1 = {out[-1] <- lapply(names(df)[-1], \(x) c(NA, x)[1L + (df[[x]] == "yes")])},
GKi2 = {out[-1] <- lapply(2:ncol(df), \(i) c(NA, names(df)[[i]])[1L + (df[[i]] == "yes")])}
)
#  expression      min  median itr/s…¹ mem_a…² gc/se…³ n_itr  n_gc total…⁴ result
#  <bch:expr> <bch:tm> <bch:t>   <dbl> <bch:b>   <dbl> <int> <dbl> <bch:t> <list>
#1 akrun1       10.2ms  11.1ms    86.6 14.68KB    8.88    39     4   451ms <NULL>
#2 akrun2      271.6µs 297.4µs  3176.   7.28KB   10.5   1518     5   478ms <NULL>
#3 r2evans     295.6µs 323.9µs  3014.   7.91KB   12.5   1452     6   482ms <NULL>
#4 GKi1        158.2µs 172.6µs  5655.  22.61KB   12.4   2739     6   484ms <NULL>
#5 GKi2        169.8µs 184.2µs  5332.  26.52KB   11.3   2363     5   443ms <NULL>
```